# What tool(s) are required to remove a Rohloff sprocket?

Tags: internally-geared-hub, sprocket, rohloff

To remove a Rohloff sprocket, I need this [Sprocket Remover Tool](https://www.rohloff.de/en/shop/product-detail?tt_products%5BbackPID%5D=1320&tt_products%5Bproduct%5D=305&cHash=91445fe57ae64c1fb5c6e2434538f626):

[image]

Do I also need the [lock ring tool](https://www.rohloff.de/en/shop/product-detail?tt_products%5BbackPID%5D=1320&tt_products%5Bproduct%5D=630&cHash=ca2e2b3466d859323fce43b2a05390e6)? If not, what is the lock ring tool required for?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The tool needed to remove a Rohloff sprocket depends on the **O.L.D (Over Locknut Dimension)** of the hub. The following picture from Sheldon Brown illustrates the O.L.D measurement on a Shimano Deore rear hub (135 mm in that case):

[image: O.L.D on Shimano Deore hub]

Rohloff has **3 different sprocket remover tools** (O.L.D between parentheses):

[image: Sprocket removal tools]

You only need one of those to remove a threaded sprocket or a splined sprocket that is installed either on the splined sprocket carrier *Art. #8540* or *Art. #8540S*.

The lock ring removal tool *Art. #8518* you mentioned is only needed to remove/install the lock ring used with splined sprocket carrier *Art. #8540L* and *Art. #8540SL*. Those sprocket carriers are mostly used for the **Gate Carbon Drive splined sprocket** which is for using a belt instead of a chain. The following picture shows the lock ring (black) with the belt sprocket (silver):

[image: Carbon drive sprocket and lock ring]